# Как узнать угол между двумя точками пересечения 2д координат?

Tags: unity3d

Нужно найти угол между векторами. Я думаю, что должна быть функция или метод, для таких вещей, но не могу найти в справочнике.

Пример использования желателен.

Comment: Находите скалярное произведение векторов, и вспоминаете известную формулу: `a•b = |a|•|b|•cos alpha`, Ну и потом берете арккосинус.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный метод
Vector3.Angle - который возвращает наименьший угол между двумя векторами
описанный в документации юнити https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html

Использовать её относительно просто

```
Vector3 targetDirection = target.transform.position - transform.position;
    angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(transform.forward, targetDirection);
```

Вуаля-  мы получили наименьший угол между нашим объектом и объектом target
Соотвественно это вполне будет работать и для д2 координат (просто z=0)
или же если вам это не удобно можно использовать (совершенно также)
Vector2.Angle
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Angle.html

Comment: Я уже разобрался, но пояснения работы метода неверные. Пример тоже.

Comment: Ну вам виднее:)